# How to add multiple users in LoginFlow - Xamarin system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, user-registration

I have sample xamarin forms solution. I wanted username and login functionality. I was doing some research and found nice example.

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/LoginFlow/

I like the way 'LoginFlow' works.

I want to hardcode the user accounts into solution and than when it comes to login user would just use their credentials which I will hard code and give them out individually.

I can see there is file called "LoginNavigation->Constants.cs". It has one user account.

My Question is how I can add multiple users in this so multiple user can login into this solution.

```
namespace LoginNavigation
 {
   public static class Constants
     {
        public static string Username = "Xamarin";
        public static string Password = "password";


       }
  }
```

**Edit**

Getting error when matching credentials with login form to directory.

**Constants.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LoginNavigation
{
    public class Constants
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "user1", "pass" },
        { "user2", "pass" },
        { "user3", "pass" }
    };

    }


}
```

On the login page; This is action when user click login.

**LoginPage.cs**

```
        async void OnLoginButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            var user = new User {
            Username = usernameEntry.Text,
            Password = passwordEntry.Text
        };

        var isValid = AreCredentialsCorrect (user);
        if (isValid) {
            App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
            //Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new MainPageCS (), this);
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPageCS(), Navigation.NavigationStack.First());
            await Navigation.PopAsync ();
        } else {
            messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
            passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }


    bool AreCredentialsCorrect (string user, string pass)
    {
        //return user.Username == Constants.Username && user.Password == Constants.Password;
        return (Credentials.ContainsKey(user) && Credentials[user] == pass);

    }
```

How I can fix above please. Thank you

Comment: use a SQLite db?  Or a Dictionary of user/pw pairs?  Or store them in a json file?  There are dozens of ways you could approach this.

Comment: The LoginFlow example does not use sqlite. It used code as above. So I am happy to keep it as above but add multiple users.

Comment: ok, then create a Dictionary

Comment: Can you help me create a directory. Not sure how to create directory. Maybe create sample directory with few users please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a dictionary with all of your user/password pairs in it

```
Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "user1", "pass" },
        { "user2", "pass" },
        { "user3", "pass" }
    };
```

then when you want to check them

```
public bool ValidateLogin(string user, string pass) 
{
  return (Credentials.ContainsKey(user) && Credentials[user] == pass);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help Jason. I tired your code but getting some error. And I believe this is because I have a login form asking user to enter login details. But I am failing to match login details with directory. I have updated my original question with code.

Comment: I have edited my original question. The new code is under 'Edit' heading. Thank you @Jason

Comment: "Getting error" is a useless description of the problem.  What specific error message are you getting, what line causes it, etc.

Comment: Hi @Jason. Thanks. I have managed to create dictionary .  Its working lovely. Thanks for your help. Can I also ask you simple question. In dictionary, we only pass 2 parameters (username & password). isit posssible to pass 3 params. username, password and ID. Eventually App will store some information. I would like to store which users is storing information by saving the user ID.

Comment: A dictionary stores key/value pairs, but both the key and the value can be of any type.  You can use a custom class for the value that stores as many values as you like.  Dictionary is a basic C# concept that is well documented.

Comment: Thanks @Jason. Would you record me to create custom class than. or is there any better way to somehow store User ID for each user. So When user will press save; I can get the user ID as well so I know which user has stored this information.